# Obtener numero de error, de toda una respuesta en json - NodeJS

Tags: nodejs

Necesito obtener de esta respuesta, solamente el numero de error. Si es 404, 403, o algun otro. Esto esta hecho en NodeJS, alguien tiene alguna idea como puedo hacer? Les dejo la respuesta.

```html
GotError: GET https://api.github.com/repos/org/repo/contents/package.json response code is 403 (Forbidden)
    at /Users/santiago/Documents/license/node_modules/got/index.js:175:12
    at BufferStream.<anonymous> (/Users//Documents/license/node_modules/read-all-stream/index.js:64:3)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at BufferStream.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at finishMaybe (/Users//Documents/license/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:513:14)
    at endWritable (/Users//Documents/license/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:523:3)
    at BufferStream.Writable.end (/Users//Documents/license/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:493:41)
    at Unzip.onend (_stream_readable.js:511:10)
    at Unzip.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20) nested: null, code: 403 }
```

```js
getFromGithub: function(allRepos, callback){
  var self = this;

  var apiRequest = api('/repos/' + self.settings.org + '/' + self.repo + '/contents/package.json', {
   token: self.settings.gitToken
  });

  apiRequest.on('data', function(response) {
   self.reposParsed = JSON.stringify(allRepos);

   var packageJSON = new PackageJSON(self.settings, self.reposParsed);
   packageJSON.parseFromString(response.content, function(){
    self.getLicenseTree(packageJSON, function(err){
     if(err)
      return callback(err, null);

     self.licenses = packageJSON.list;

     callback(null, self.licenses);
    });
   });
  });

  apiRequest.on('error', function(err) {
   console.log(err);
   callback(err, null);
  });
 },
```

Comment: Cuál es el código que hace la consulta?

Comment: Ahi lo edite y puse el codigo, saludos

Comment: Esta tirando error el codigo @SantiagoD'Antuoni

Comment: Comprueba el parámetro response, debería tener una propiedad status si he entendido el código que pasas